# Html.ActionLink and HTML as parameter (ASP.Net MVC 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

```
Html.ActionLink("<span class=\"title\">Retry</span><span class=\"arrow\"></span>", "Login", "User")
```

Hi,

If I execute above code in ASP.Net MVC 2, I get the following output on my screen:
[Error? http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2069/screenerror.png](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2069/screenerror.png)

How do I disable the escaping of the code, so my span is within the ActionLink, and not displayed as output?

I know this is expected behavior, to keep it safe, but I want it to interpret the HTML code I pass as a parameter.

Thanks!
Yvan

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? <a><span></span></a>? I dont think that valid html or xhtml!

Comment: Ok - so I was smoking my socks with my initial comment, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379392/what-elements-can-be-contained-within-a-a-tag

Comment: I'm using iWebkit (http://www.iwebkit.net) to create native-looking websites for the iPhone. I'm desinging a Mafia-Wars style RPG ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ActionLink` helper method can only be used for plain-text links.

You should manually make an `<a>` tag, like this:

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("Login", "User") %>">
    <span class="title">Retry</span><span class="arrow"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: How should I do that? I know how to make an <a> tag, but which must be the href parameter? I'm quite new to all this MVC-stuff ;)

Comment: Thank you! This helped me out, since I want to deploy on IIS 6, and from the things I read, I need to change some settings, which will render hardcoded paths in the href parameter invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following also works.

```
<span class="title"><%= html.actionlink("Retry","Login", "User") %></span><span 
class="arrow"></span>
```

I mean, <.span>Retry<./span> is just <.span>plaintext<./span> which is the same as the actionlink text? ("." inserted for SO)