# What elements can be contained within a <a> tag?

Tags: html, validation, html4

What are the valid html elements, if any, that can be contained within a `<a>` tag?

Comment: [The MDN `a` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) says "Permitted content: Transparent, containing either [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) or [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Inline elements ( `a, span, strong, em` among others ) can contain other inline elements and text nodes. An anchor can contain a span, which can contain a text node.

> Generally, block-level elements may
>   contain inline elements and other
>   block-level elements. Generally,
>   inline elements may contain only data
>   and other inline elements. Inherent in
>   this structural distinction is the
>   idea that block elements create
>   "larger" structures than inline
>   elements.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

As noted in other answers, you can't nest an `a` in an `a`.

Comment: so `<a><span>ble</span></a` is valid since they are both inline elements, right?

Comment: You can find out if you make a html document and validate @ http://validator.w3.org/ :)

Comment: question was actually inspired by another SO question :). I'm not actually doing this and somehow dont ever see myself using a `<span>` within an `<a>`.. Thanks.. another 6 minutes to go before i can mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 81):

As of HTML 5, `<a>` may contain not only (valid) inline elements, but also block elements, etc.

W3: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element:concept-element-content-model

Comment: Nice find. It's also worth noting its parent must be an element that is allowed to contain block elements.

Comment: The precise link to the paragraph that discuss this question: http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html#a-changes

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: The link in the answer was dead so I fixed it, but I like the context given on the page @Laizer mentions.

Answer (score 3):

An `<a>` tag can contain any [Inline Element](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html) besides another `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

See the [anchor section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2) of the specification.

```
<!ELEMENT A - - (%inline;)* -(A)       -- anchor -->
```

The relevant section is `(%inline;)* -(A)`, which means "Anything in the group %inline excluding A elements". [%inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#inline) is hyperlinked to make it easier for you to expand it.

Answer (score 1):

It can contain plain text and inline elements. Inline elements are following:

```
TT | I | B | BIG | SMALL | EM | STRONG | DFN | CODE | SAMP | 
KBD | VAR | CITE | ABBR | ACRONYM | A | IMG | OBJECT | BR | 
SCRIPT | MAP | Q | SUB | SUP | SPAN | BDO
```

But `A` can not be nested in another `A` and nesting `SCRIPT` doesn't make senese.

Comment: You forgot the [formctrl](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#formctrl) elements there. (Hell, who would use a `select` inside an `a`?)

Comment: I forgot them by intention :) There is no need to nesting forms elements in anchor. Maybe without href attribute, but who use it today? :)

Comment: Why doesn't nesting script make sense?  If I have text/plain it would be nice to treat that nested script tag as data and not a tag.

Answer (score 1):

An anchor tag is an inline element, so it can contain other inline elements (except other anchor tags).

If you want to put a block element inside an anchor, you have to use an inline element and turn it into a block element using CSS, along with the anchor tag itself.

Example:

```
<a href="page.html" class="blocklink"><span>eat me</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.blocklink { display: block; }
.blocklink span { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below example completes @aya answer from https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element:concept-element-content-model:

> The `a` element can be wrapped around entire `paragraphs`, `lists`,
> `tables`, and so forth, even entire `sections`, so long as there is no
> interactive content within (e.g., buttons or other links).

```
<aside>
 <h1>Advertising</h1>
 <a href="https://www.example.com">
  <section>
   <h1>Fun Travel!</h1>
   <p>Travel to Neverland</p>
   <p>$9.99 + free transfer.</p>
  </section>
 </a>
 <a href="https://www.example.com">
  <section>
   <h1>Family Fun!</h1>
   <p>Visit us at Freeland</p>
   <p>No charge!</p>
  </section>
 </a>
</aside>
```