# Browsers rendering multiple nested a tags

Tags: html

Imagine this block of HTML:

```
<a href="/somewhere/">
    <div class="nested">
        <div class="sub-nested">
            <div class="sub-sub-nested">
                <a href="/else/">button</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

This gets rendered in my browsers like this:

```
<a href="/somewhere/"></a>
<div class="nested">
    <a href="/somewhere/"></a>
    <div class="sub-nested">
        <a href="/somewhere/"></a>
        <div class="sub-sub-nested">
            <a href="/somewhere/"></a>
            <a href="/else/">button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This happens only if there is another `a` tag inside the outer `a` tag.

I totally don't understand why this is happening. How this could even be. And it's driving me insane.

The problem looks so basic, that i wonder what it was about the HTML standard that i have misunderstood? After all, shouldn't as of HTML5 any tags be allowed within `a` tags?

What am i missing here?

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what you speak of, sir.

Comment: You can't nest anchor tags, no matter what may be in between them.

Comment: Ah, thanks for freshening me up. While researching i ran into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379392/what-elements-can-be-contained-within-a-a-tag where i read 80% of the first answer and concluded it must be possible. Now i re-read it and realised it is not a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't next anchor tags. As the [W3 says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2):

> 12.2.2 Nested links are illegal
>
> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A
>   element must not contain any other A elements.

Comment: I feel very illegal now. I better go fix it quickly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you try to [validate](http://validator.w3.org) your code, you will get

> Document type does not allow element "div" here; (...)
>
> One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put
>   a block-level element (such as "`<p>`" or "`<table>`") inside an inline
>   element (such as "`<a>`", "`<span>`", or "`<font>`").

So you can't put a `<div>` inside an `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on why you can't nest A tags, the browser would not know where to direct the user, since the multiple A tags would have multiple HREF attributes. This is why it is illegal to nest A tags.