# Unwanted <a> tags in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, anchor

I have a problem with the way WordPress creates code.

As shown below, my articles should be wrapped inside an `<a>` tag. WordPress creates a few extra  wraps and I don't know how to get rid of them.

Does anyone has an idea?

This:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article class="post-thumb">

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail();} ?>
            <div class="post-thumb-caption">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="post-thumb-caption-hover">
                <div class="post-thumb-caption-hover-center">
                    <img id="menu-icon" class="icons svg" src="icons/menu21.svg"></img>
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <h3><?php the_category(', ') ?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
    </a>
</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php post_navigation(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2><?php _e('Nothing Found','html5reset'); ?></h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Should result in this:

```
<article class="post-thumb">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="3a.jpg" id="image">
            <div class="post-thumb-caption">
                <h2>Titel</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="post-thumb-caption-hover">
                <div class="post-thumb-caption-hover-center">
                    <img id="menu-icon" class="icons svg" src="icons/menu21.svg">
                    <h2>Titel</h2>
                    <h3>Categorie</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
    </a>
</article>
```

But WordPress creates this:

```
<article class="post-thumb">

    <a href="http://localhost/sm/titel/">
        <img width="300" height="300" src="http://localhost/sm/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/3a.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="3a">             <div class="post-thumb-caption">
                <h2>Titel</h2>
            </div>
            </a><div class="post-thumb-caption-hover"><a href="http://localhost/sm/Titel/">
                </a><div class="post-thumb-caption-hover-center"><a href="http://localhost/sm/Titel/">
                    <img id="menu-icon" class="icons svg" src="icons/menu21.svg">
                    <h2>Willem en Henk</h2>
                    </a><h3><a href="http://localhost/sm/Titel/"></a><a href="http://localhost/sm/category/ontbijt/" title="Alle berichten bekijken in Ontbijt" rel="category tag">Ontbijt</a>, <a href="http://localhost/sm/category/snacks/" title="Alle berichten bekijken in Snacks" rel="category tag">Snacks</a></h3>
                </div>
            </div>

</article>
```

Comment: What DOCTYPE is your document? I ask because your target HTML is invalid in anything before HTML5, mostly because [an `<a>` element can only contain other inline elements in earlier HTML versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379392/what-elements-can-be-contained-within-a-a-tag). Is it possible that your actual output is fine, but your browser is correcting the DOM in-memory to be valid, and that's what you're seeing? How are you inspecting the output, exactly? (The clue for me is that your `<a>` is closed just before the first non-inline element within it, the `<div>`)

Comment: <!doctype html>, so it should be working right?
The output how I'm inspecting it is posted at the bottom of my initial post. I've inspected it in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Strange thing is, I've coded the structure before adding the WordPress tags and everything worked fine. After including the WordPress tags, the code seems broken.

Comment: In your WordPress settings, under Settings->Writing, do you have " WordPress should correct invalidly nested XHTML automatically" checked?

Comment: Nope, that's unchecked

Comment: Okay, I officially give up. I can't see how WordPress could be doing that, especially as you're not even outputting the_content()..

Comment: `<?php the_category(', ') ?>` should be `<?php the_category(); ?>` if blank.

Comment: @karlonorg did any answer or comment help you?

Comment: @yeshansachithak nope, unfortunately not.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

to

```
<a href="#">
```

and it should fix that problem.

Comment: his problem are the additional anchor-tags

Comment: That isn't a solution. I need 
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
but only once.

Comment: @Howlin is correct as far as the permalink not being a blank anchor.