# CSS- Make Entire Div Clickable by putting the div in <a href=#> is not working

Tags: html, css

I have to make entire div with another elements inside it clickable.
I do it by writing the dive inside  `<a href="#"> </a>` like this:

```
<a href="#">
     <div class="detail padding-lg full-width like-on-post">
        <div class="avtar round  pull-left">
            <span class="user-personal-pic default-user-avtar border circle             avtar user-image you-menu ">
               <g:if test="${usrHeader?.avatarUrl?.indexOf('no-avatar')    ==-1 || usrHeader?.avatarUrl?.length() == 0 || usrHeader?.avatarUrl == null}">
              <img src="${usrHeader?.avatarUrl}" width="34" height="34" alt="Avatar" />
                 </g:if>

             </span>
            </div>
         <div class="detail-container">
                <p class="name">${usrHeader?.fullName()}</p>
               <p class="footer mouse-over"><g:link controller="connection" action="details">View profile</g:link></p>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </a>
```

For some reason instead putting the entire div to  `<a href="#"> </a>` it put each element to different  `<a href="#"> </a>`.

How I can I entire to aall div to  `<a href="#"> </a>`?

Comment: I think `<g:link>` will produce an anchor tag, so you cannot nest anchor inside an anchor hence it doen't work for you

Comment: In addition to the point made by Mr. Alien, `div` are block level elements and are not valid within `a` tags. For more info please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379392/what-elements-can-be-contained-within-a-a-tag. A way round this may be to use `span` tags instead and change them to `display: block;` in css.

Answer (score 1):

By default a `<a>` tag is displayed `inline`, any inline element is not really affected by `padding`, so if you want to make a button that is clickable everywhere inside it, make an empty `div` put the `<a>` in it and give it `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` then you can add padding to it to expend it, or use width, depends what u need to do, here is a small [Example](http://codepen.io/ZetCoby/pen/jEeqdr)

```
<div class="btn"><a href="#">Button</a></div>

a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  background:#262626;
  font-family:Arial;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}
a:hover{
  background:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add `display:block` on `a` tag on css. Pleas try this one hope it will work

Comment: Don't you mean like this?

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example having a tag inside div and a made to display:block and width and height 100% so whole div is now clickable.

Whole div is clickable

```css
div{
background:green;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid blue;

}
a{
  background:yellow;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="http://google.co.in">google</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the div clickable, do

```
<div onclick="/*Your JavaScript Code*/" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

This should work for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kw57sqvf/7/)**

CSS:

```
a {
    display:block;
    background-color:yellow;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a span {
    display:block;
    background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Set target for `<a>`

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent div relative positioned, and put in it an anchor tag with position:absolute, setting top:0,right:0,bottom:0 and left:0.