# Hover effect lost on image, when mouse moves over absolutely positioned nephew text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image with some text positioned over it.

When I hover the cursor over the image, I change the color of box-shadow.

Unfortunately, when the cursor reaches the text overlaid on top of the image, the background image loses the hover effect.

How can I keep the hover effect on the image, while the cursor is on the nephew text element?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x200.png">
      <div class="text-overlay">
         <h2><span>Example</span><br>Overlay<br>Text</h2>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #b2b2b2;
}

img:hover {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #f47c20;
}

.text-overlay {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 32px;
}
```

Example codepen: https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/bLGqbP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the hover on the `a` tag :

**Codepen** : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJNyQp

```css
img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #b2b2b2;
}

a:hover img {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #f47c20;
}

.text-overlay {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x200.png">
      <div class="text-overlay">
         <h2><span>Example</span><br>Overlay<br>Text</h2>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just show the text, you can use `pointer-events:none` to the text class `.text-overlay`.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #b2b2b2;
}

img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #f47c20;
}

.text-overlay {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 32px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x200.png">
    <div class="text-overlay">
      <h2><span>Example</span><br>Overlay<br>Text</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Recommendation

Never put `div` within `a` tag, you need to use inline elements.

> Inline elements ( a, span, strong, em among others ) can contain other inline elements and text nodes. An anchor can contain a span, which can contain a text node. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379407/1715121)

- Set the HOVER to your `a` element.

The following code snippet uses the `text-overlay` class on your `h2` tag.

```css
img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #b2b2b2;
}

a:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #f47c20;
}

.text-overlay {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">

  <a href="#">
      <h2 class='text-overlay'><span>Example</span><br>Overlay<br>Text</h2>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x200.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to some changes in your css

```
img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #b2b2b2;
}

a:hover img {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #f47c20;
}

.text-overlay {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 32px;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the text is not the child for the img, but a nephew (as it's the child of it's div sibling).

Anyway, you can fix that either by going 
.text-overlay {
  pointer-events:none;
}

or adjusting your html structure as described in other anwsers