# Why this mouseenter event does not work on an <i> tag inside <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I would like to know why this `mouseenter` event is never get call. Change the parent to `ul tag` and everything works

I set up an jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/4vfqgz7x/1/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**  Even jsfiddle may not be available in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot have an `a` element residing **within** another `a` element.

```html
<a>
  <li class="complete">1</li>
  <li class="complete">2</li>
  <a>3</a>
  <i>4</i>
</a>
```

If you run and inspect the above code snippet, you will see the result in the DOM is actually:

```
<a>
    <li class="complete">1</li>
    <li class="complete">2</li>
</a>
<a>3</a>
<i>4</i>
```

Thus, your CSS Selector of `a > i` (*select all* `i` *elements where the parent is an* `a` *element*) is not going to work.

---

Reference: [What elements can be contained within a <a> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3379392)

Comment: Flagging as duplicate would suffice, no need to re-answer questions already having an answer. As the answer mentionned in your "reference" is enough. `An <a> tag can contain any Inline Element besides another <a> tag.`